# AEM 6.2 create backup issue

Tags: aem

While creating new online backup of my Author instance it is showing error showing below:

[image]

In the log it is showing error:

```
30.11.2017 12:11:59.105 *ERROR* [112.196.146.254 [1512043919094] GET /libs/granite/backup/content/createBackup/content/items/backupform.check.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ubuntu/AEM/Dev/author/crx-quickstart/launchpad/felix/bundle305/data/classes/org/apache/jsp/libs/granite/backup/components/backupform/check_html_jsp.java (Permission denied)
    at org.apache.sling.commons.fsclassloader.impl.FSClassLoaderProvider.getOutputStream(FSClassLoaderProvider.java:225)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.SlingIOProvider.getOutputStream(SlingIOProvider.java:145)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getOutputStream(JspCompilationContext.java:146)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:150)
```

I have checked the bundle 305 is active. Can anyone suggest why it is unable to create a backup and showing this error.

Comment: What user started the AEM process? Does that user have read/write permissions to the `/home/ubuntu/AEM/Dev/Backup` catalogue? This error looks like it's caused by filesystem-level permissions.

Comment: Thanks @toniedzwiedz. I think this is the answer for my question. Can you move this comment to answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be dealing with filesystem-level permissions problem.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
/home/ubuntu/AEM/Dev/(...)/check_html_jsp.java (Permission denied)
```

This error tells you that the AEM process was denied permission to access or save a file at the path provided.

Check which user started AEM and if the user has the permissions necessary to access the directory that you're trying to use (`/home/ubuntu/AEM/Dev`). Change the path or the permissions.

Comment: Starting AEM instance with Sudo account, fixed my problem.

Comment: Keep in mind that giving AEM root access is a bad idea. It's a web application and it's a potential attack vector. AEM should ideally have a dedicated user with minimal permissions sufficient for it to function. Otherwise you risk someone compromising the security of the machine running it.